# Airflow backfill not working

Tags: python-2.7, scheduler, airflow

I am running a workflow DAG using airflow. The start date i have set is 5/26/2014 and schedule_interval is 1 day without an end date and it is using a Celery Executor. Airflow starts running my tasks from the given date and incrementally for each day from start date as expected.

But the problem is, it will schedule and run the dags only for 16 days from the start date and then stop. i have to restart the scheduler service for it to schedule the next set of dags and run.

I have modified the properties below to set them at higher in airflow.cfg but still it doesn't work,

```
dag_concurrency = 9999
max_active_runs_per_dag = 9999
parallellism = 9999
celeryd_concurrency = 4
```

My requirement is to have airflow execute my tasks from the start date till the current date. Looks like there is a limit on the number of dags it can run but i can't get to figure that out. Please suggest.

My airflow version is 1.7.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right, do you want to run a daily job from a certain date until the next 16 days? 
If so, it does not have anything to do with *airflow.cfg*, the setting you posted could actually "kill" your machine in case you have a lot of Dags, this is about the task-instances that will run and be scheduled in parallel.

I guess what you need is to define a *start_date* and *end_date*.
You can do it when you contruct the DAG that will hold the job.
One way is to define the default_args and then use them on your dag.

```
default_args = {
     'owner': 'userXX',
     'start_date': datetime(2014, 05, 26),
     'end_date': datetime(2014, 06, 11),
     'email': ['mail1..','mail2...'],
    ...
}

mydag = DAG(
           PARENT_ID, default_args=default_args,
           schedule_interval="@daily",
           user_defined_macros=user_defined_macros
)

_some_Operator(
                task_id='task_idxx',
                .. other settings/jobrun...
                dag=mydag,

            )
```

Hope this helps

Comment: typo for `start_date` to `end_date` at your comment.

Comment: i've got the same problem and these two params do not help :(